# accessing wcf from mvc view trough js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm trying to learn wcf on practical example. I followed [scalable wcf solution tutorial](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Architectural-Overview-Creating-Streamlined-Simplified-yet-Scalable-WCF-Connectivity#WCFConnectivityImplementation) and my service works ok, client from my console app. works ok. But what I want to achive is consuming my service trough js from mvc view (razor) page. On my client console application I'm accessing to proxy with

```
IService proxy = new ChannelFactory<IService>(Configuration.MyServiceActiveEndpoint).CreateChannel();
List<MyObjectDto> data = proxy.GetMyData();
```

...
how to practicaly achive this creating proxy client from mvc view page (without adding service reference). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't do this.. you really really don't.  This completely breaks the entire point of Model-View-Controller (MVC).  The controller should be the one accessing the WCF service and returning the data to the View.

Answer (score 0):

Check out servicestack.net for the cleanest and best web service implementation in .net.  No config, easily callable from jQuery, and returns json by default.  Easy to get started with NuGet Mvc 3 package.

Comment: sure, thank you, but right now I want to solve this problem. So anyone ?

Comment: should I need to create proxy inside controller to create channel which will communicate with service ?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are using already registers an endpoint with the enableWebScript behavior - you should get a js proxy generated automatically when you access http://server/virtualdirectory/X.svc/json url. Include that js file in your mvc view.

If you host the wcf service in the MVC web app you can use Url.Content:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/X.svc/json")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then just invoke the service from js - use the javascript from this post as an example: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx

Comment: Note this is an answer to HOW to consume WCF service from js. It does not consider the question if this is the right thing to do from an MVC web app - [ShaneCourtrille's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508016/829181) covers that.